# read Excel cells into Stata global as variables

Tags: excel, variables, import, stata

There are several panel datasets I'd like to join.

The observations in these datasets are identified by an id variable and a variable identifying the time the observation was made.
All datasets include some variables I need, some I don't need and never the same variables (excluding the id and the survey-time-variable).

The datasets are huge, so to speed up processing and decrease the size of the final dataset, I want to `drop` all variables I don't need.

Thoose variables are stored in an Excel file with several columns. One of these columns, say, C2, contains all my variable names.

Now I believe I have two possible ways to follow, which I describe in order of my favour:

1) Read in the variable-names from the Excel file into a global in Stata and then state:

```
keep global varlist
```

That way only variables I need should be retained.

2) Generate a new empty dataset with all the variables from the Excel file and then

```
joinby id syear $varlist using dataset, update
```

Anyhow I need to read out the variables from the excel file into a global. 
I realize that I could do this by just copy and paste from Excel into Stata, but I suppose there will be some changes in the variables as I go along with the work and I want to learn how to program properly in Stata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading the variable names into a `local`, and use only `global` if strictly necessary.

One way to do that is to use `import excel` along with `levelsof`:

```
clear
set more off

// import from MS Excel and create local
import excel using myvars.xlsx, cellrange(B2:B5) firstrow
levelsof myvars, local(tokeep) clean

// use local
clear
sysuse auto
describe

keep `tokeep'
describe
```

The MS Excel file reads

```
myvars
make
mpg
weight
```

in the corresponding cells.

The result :

```
. // import from MS Excel and create local
. import excel using myvars.xlsx, cellrange(B2:B5) firstrow

. levelsof myvars, local(tokeep) clean
make mpg weight

. 
. // use local
. clear

. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. describe

Contains data from C:\Program Files (x86)\Stata13\ado\base/a/auto.dta
  obs:            74                          1978 Automobile Data
 vars:            12                          13 Apr 2013 17:45
 size:         3,182                          (_dta has notes)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
make            str18   %-18s                 Make and Model
price           int     %8.0gc                Price
mpg             int     %8.0g                 Mileage (mpg)
rep78           int     %8.0g                 Repair Record 1978
headroom        float   %6.1f                 Headroom (in.)
trunk           int     %8.0g                 Trunk space (cu. ft.)
weight          int     %8.0gc                Weight (lbs.)
length          int     %8.0g                 Length (in.)
turn            int     %8.0g                 Turn Circle (ft.)
displacement    int     %8.0g                 Displacement (cu. in.)
gear_ratio      float   %6.2f                 Gear Ratio
foreign         byte    %8.0g      origin     Car type
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:  foreign

. 
. keep `tokeep'

. describe

Contains data from C:\Program Files (x86)\Stata13\ado\base/a/auto.dta
  obs:            74                          1978 Automobile Data
 vars:             3                          13 Apr 2013 17:45
 size:         1,628                          (_dta has notes)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
make            str18   %-18s                 Make and Model
mpg             int     %8.0g                 Mileage (mpg)
weight          int     %8.0gc                Weight (lbs.)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:  
     Note:  dataset has changed since last saved

. 
end of do-file
```

See also `help file read`, but for your case, it seems an unnecessarily complicated path.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Is it possible to set the row wich should be used for varnames to another then the first row?

Comment: You can place it anywhere you want as long as it's in the same column as your variable names. `import excel` has an option to set the range to import (see my example). The option `firstrow` indicates that the first row **of the imported range** holds the name of the variable to be imported, nothing else. Check `help import` carefully.  Check also the content of the local macro before dropping.